# Using <picture> and <srcset> for clickable images using media queries

Tags: html, image, target, srcset

I need to be able to make this as a link and have the subsequent linked page show the correct image file based on screen size. The html was working to choose the correct image before i added the a href. Is there a way to accomplish what I'm seeking?

```
<picture class="imagesVerticalGallery">
<!--small img -->
<a href="http://sofialeiby.com/update/img/abc/1abcinstall_1200.jpg">
<source srcset="http://sofialeiby.com/update/img/abc/1abcinstall_1200.jpg"   media="(min-width: 768px)"></a>

<!--large img -->
<a href="http://sofialeiby.com/update/img/abc/1abcinstall.jpg">
<source srcset="http://sofialeiby.com/update/img/abc/1abcinstall.jpg"></a>


<!--default large img --> 
<a href="http://sofialeiby.com/update/img/abc/1abcinstall.jpg">
<img srcset="http://sofialeiby.com/update/img/abc/1abcinstall.jpg"></a> 
</picture>
```

[my attempt is here, top image](http://sofialeiby.com/#abcdefghijklmnop)

Answer (score 1):

So the image is presented through the `img srcset` so in theory, and **this will not work**, you would need to add an anchor tag around the img specifically and call the sources via a srcset:

```
<picture>
<source srcset="1380.jpg"media="(min-width: 1380px)">
<source srcset="990.jpg"media="(min-width: 990px)">
<source srcset="640.jpg"media="(min-width: 640px)">
<a srcset="320.jpg"">
<img srcset="320.jpg">
</a> 
</picture>
```

But this above will not work as HTML alone.

**You could do something like this:**

```
<a href="newpage.html">
<picture>
<source srcset="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=1380%C3%97150&w=1380&h=150" media="(min-width: 1380px)">
<source srcset="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=900%C3%97150&w=900&h=150" media="(min-width: 990px)">
<source srcset="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=650%C3%97150&w=650&h=150" media="(min-width: 640px)">
<img srcset="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150">
</picture>
</a>
```

Then on the new page:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; height=device-height;">
<style>
</style>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<picture>
<source srcset="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=1380%C3%97150&w=1380&h=150" media="(min-width: 1380px)">
<source srcset="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=900%C3%97150&w=900&h=150" media="(min-width: 990px)">
<source srcset="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=650%C3%97150&w=650&h=150" media="(min-width: 640px)">
<img srcset="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150">
</picture>

</body>
</html>
```